# Drupal 7 computed field value in view

Tags: views, nodes, theming, entities

I'm really stuck displaying content type's computed field in view. Computed field value calculated properly and stored in database (value is a generated HTML code), but in view I get HTML just printed out as text. Looking through the page source code I found that HTML tags are encoded and looks like that `&lt;a href=&quot;LINK_HERE&quot;&gt;` So I'm wondering how to display custom field's HTML in view (seems to me that was a some custom module for this purpose?)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**
Seems that I should to check the "Formatter" dropdown menu, it has a "Unsinitized" which perfectly works in my case.

Answer (score 0):

In Views, try this:

- add the field as normal, exclude from display
- create a new field, Global:Custom Text
- add the field name as a Replacement Pattern

It's likely that for security reasons it is psuedo-sanitizing the html. Global: Custom Text should display it as is, but I haven't tried it under these circumstances, so it may not.

Comment: Very tricky idea but unfortunately this doesn't worked out. I also trued same thing with Global: PHP and also nothing. But I figuared out the solution - at some moment the "Unsinitized" option appears in Formatter dropdown at the field configuration. So this actually prints HTML out.

Comment: well good - once you're permitted, be sure to add that as an answer and Accept it, so this question doesn't appear unanswered going forward.